# Run Workflow against existing Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a Custom List that has a Choice Field Yes/No. I need to run a workflow against this list for all items with a Yes value. I see how to run a workflow for new or changed items, but this isn't the case for my need. I need the ability to have a Workflow search through the list and if the value is yes create a task in another list.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a SharePoint 2013 workflow but it's not that easy. You will have to use the Call HTTP Web Service workflow activity to retrieve all list items that match your query. Then you can loop though the result and create your tasks.

There are several tutorials out there that show you how to do that. Here are the links to a few of them:

- [Workflow Loop Through Multiple SharePoint Items](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/08/01/workflow-loop-through-multiple-sharepoint-items/)
- [Loop Through SharePoint Custom List Items in SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/313769/loop-through-sharepoint-custom-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [Looping Through List Items in SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflows](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thank you Daniel I am going to give this a try. I will keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

I added a new single line of text column to the list named "workflow trigger". I then used quick edit to change the value in the  first row of this column to "1", copied the cell, selected the rest of the cells in this column and pasted. The change runs the workflow on all items.

Answer (score 0):

You can set workflows to be manually triggered: [Manually start a workflow on a document or item](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-start-a-workflow-on-a-document-or-item-839bd98c-6eac-4dca-a1f5-8916430accf3)
However, there is no OOTB way to automatically search through the list like this.  Workflows run on and are associated with a single item at a time, not a whole list.

You could look into timer jobs, which may be closer to what you're looking for, but I can't speak to that, as I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: A manual trigger would not be a solution - there are about 500 items with the value of Yes. This is a SharePoint Online Site - will timer jobs work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a workflow with a logic condition (with SharePoint Designer).
For exemple : 
Create a workflow on Item added (Allow the Manual start too),

- Get your ListItem
- check the value of your Yes/No Field
- if the value is = Yes

  - create a task in your other list
- Else : do nothing
- End Of Workflow

For your old list item (with no workflow launched). After create and ADD this workflow on your list, you can do a Manual Start on all your list items